# "moov atom not found" when using av_interleaved_write_frame but not avio_write

Tags: ffmpeg, libavcodec, x264

I am attempting to put together a class that can take arbitrary frames and construct a video from it using the ffmpeg 3.3.3 API. I've been struggling to find a good example for this as the examples still seem to be using deprecated functions, so I've attempted to patch this using the documentation in the headers and by referring to a few github repos that seem to be using the new version.

If I use av_interleaved_write_frame to write the encoded packets to the output then ffprobe outputs the following:

```
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0000000002760120] moov atom not found0
X:\Diagnostics.mp4: Invalid data found when processing input
```

ffplay is unable to play the file generated using this method.

If I instead swap it out for a call to avio_write, ffprobe instead outputs:

```
Input #0, h264, from 'X:\Diagnostics.mp4':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 672x380 [SAR 1:1 DAR 168:95], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
```

ffplay can *mostly* play this file until it gets towards the end, when it outputs:

```
Input #0, h264, from 'X:\Diagnostics.mp4':    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 672x380 [SAR 1:1 DAR 168:95], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1200k tbn, 50 tbc
[h264 @ 000000000254ef80] error while decoding MB 31 22, bytestream -65
[h264 @ 000000000254ef80] concealing 102 DC, 102 AC, 102 MV errors in I frame
    nan M-V:    nan fd=   1 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0
```

VLC cannot play files from either method. The second method's file displays a single black frame then hides the video output. The first does not display anything. Neither of them give a video duration.

Does anyone have any ideas what's happening here? I assume my solution is close to working as I'm getting a good chunk of valid frames coming through.

Code:

```
void main()
{
    OutputStream Stream( "Output.mp4", 672, 380, 25, true );
    Stream.Initialize();

    int i = 100;
    while( i-- )
    {
        //... Generate a frame

        Stream.WriteFrame( Frame );
    }
    Stream.CloseFile();
}

OutputStream::OutputStream( const std::string& Path, unsigned int Width, unsigned int Height, int Framerate, bool IsBGR )
: Stream()
, FrameIndex( 0 )
{
    auto& ID = *m_InternalData;

    ID.Path = Path;

    ID.Width = Width;
    ID.Height= Height;
    ID.Framerate.num = Framerate;
    ID.Framerate.den = 1;

    ID.PixelFormat = IsBGR ? AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24 : AV_PIX_FMT_RGB24;
    ID.CodecID = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
    ID.CodecTag = 0;

    ID.AspectRatio.num = 1;
    ID.AspectRatio.den = 1;
}

CameraStreamError OutputStream::Initialize()
{
    av_log_set_callback( &InputStream::LogCallback );
    av_register_all();
    avformat_network_init();

    auto& ID = *m_InternalData;

    av_init_packet( &ID.Packet );

    int Result = avformat_alloc_output_context2( &ID.FormatContext, nullptr, nullptr, ID.Path.c_str() );
    if( Result < 0 || !ID.FormatContext )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( UnknownError );
    }

    AVCodec* Encoder = avcodec_find_encoder( ID.CodecID );

    if( !Encoder )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( NoH264Support );
    }

    AVStream* OutStream = avformat_new_stream( ID.FormatContext, Encoder );
    if( !OutStream )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( UnknownError );
    }

    ID.CodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3( Encoder );
    if( !ID.CodecContext )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( NoH264Support );
    }

    ID.CodecContext->time_base = av_inv_q(ID.Framerate);

    {
        AVCodecParameters* CodecParams = OutStream->codecpar;

        CodecParams->width = ID.Width;
        CodecParams->height = ID.Height;
        CodecParams->format = AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P;
        CodecParams->codec_id = ID.CodecID;
        CodecParams->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
        CodecParams->profile = FF_PROFILE_H264_MAIN;
        CodecParams->level = 40;

        Result = avcodec_parameters_to_context( ID.CodecContext, CodecParams );
        if( Result < 0 )
        {
            STREAM_ERROR( EncoderCreationError );
        }
    }

    if( ID.IsVideo )
    {
        ID.CodecContext->width = ID.Width;
        ID.CodecContext->height = ID.Height;
        ID.CodecContext->sample_aspect_ratio = ID.AspectRatio;
        ID.CodecContext->time_base = av_inv_q(ID.Framerate);

        if( Encoder->pix_fmts )
        {
            ID.CodecContext->pix_fmt = Encoder->pix_fmts[0];
        }
        else
        {
            ID.CodecContext->pix_fmt = ID.PixelFormat;
        }
    }
    //Snip

    Result = avcodec_open2( ID.CodecContext, Encoder, nullptr );
    if( Result < 0 )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( EncoderCreationError );
    }

    Result = avcodec_parameters_from_context( OutStream->codecpar, ID.CodecContext );
    if( Result < 0 )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( EncoderCreationError );
    }

    if( ID.FormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER )
    {
        ID.CodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;
    }

    OutStream->time_base = ID.CodecContext->time_base;
    OutStream->avg_frame_rate= av_inv_q(OutStream->time_base);

    if( !( ID.FormatContext->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE ) )
    {
        Result = avio_open( &ID.FormatContext->pb, ID.Path.c_str(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE );
        if( Result < 0 )
        {
            STREAM_ERROR( FileNotWriteable );
        }
    }

    Result = avformat_write_header( ID.FormatContext, nullptr );
    if( Result < 0 )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( WriteFailed );
    }

    ID.Output = std::make_unique<FFMPEG::Frame>( ID.CodecContext->width, ID.CodecContext->height, ID.CodecContext->pix_fmt );

    ID.ConversionContext = sws_getCachedContext(
        ID.ConversionContext,
        ID.Width,
        ID.Height,
        ID.PixelFormat,
        ID.CodecContext->width,
        ID.CodecContext->height,
        ID.CodecContext->pix_fmt,
        SWS_BICUBIC,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL );

    return CameraStreamError::Success;
}

CameraStreamError OutputStream::WriteFrame( FFMPEG::Frame* Frame )
{
    auto& ID = *m_InternalData;

    ID.Output->Prepare();

    int OutputSliceSize = sws_scale( m_InternalData->ConversionContext, Frame->GetFrame()->data, Frame->GetFrame()->linesize, 0, Frame->GetHeight(), ID.Output->GetFrame()->data, ID.Output->GetFrame()->linesize );

    ID.Output->GetFrame()->pts = ID.CodecContext->frame_number;

    int Result = avcodec_send_frame( GetData().CodecContext, ID.Output->GetFrame() );
    if( Result == AVERROR(EAGAIN) )
    {
        CameraStreamError ResultErr = SendAll();
        if( ResultErr != CameraStreamError::Success )
        {
            return ResultErr;
        }
        Result = avcodec_send_frame( GetData().CodecContext, ID.Output->GetFrame() );
    }

    if( Result == 0 )
    {
        CameraStreamError ResultErr = SendAll();
        if( ResultErr != CameraStreamError::Success )
        {
            return ResultErr;
        }
    }

    FrameIndex++;

    return CameraStreamError::Success;
}

CameraStreamError OutputStream::SendAll( void )
{
    auto& ID = *m_InternalData;

    int Result;
    do 
    {
        AVPacket TempPacket = {};
        av_init_packet( &TempPacket );

        Result = avcodec_receive_packet( GetData().CodecContext, &TempPacket );
        if( Result == 0 )
        {
            av_packet_rescale_ts( &TempPacket, ID.CodecContext->time_base, ID.FormatContext->streams[0]->time_base );

            TempPacket.stream_index = ID.FormatContext->streams[0]->index;

            //avio_write( ID.FormatContext->pb, TempPacket.data, TempPacket.size );
            Result = av_interleaved_write_frame( ID.FormatContext, &TempPacket );
            if( Result < 0 )
            {
                STREAM_ERROR( WriteFailed );
            }

            av_packet_unref( &TempPacket );
        }
        else if( Result != AVERROR(EAGAIN) )
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if( Result != AVERROR_EOF )
        {
            break;
        }
        else if( Result < 0 )
        {
            STREAM_ERROR( WriteFailed );
        }
    } while ( Result == 0);

    return CameraStreamError::Success;
}

CameraStreamError OutputStream::CloseFile()
{
    auto& ID = *m_InternalData;

    while( true )
    {
        //Flush
        int Result = avcodec_send_frame( ID.CodecContext, nullptr );
        if( Result == 0 )
        {
            CameraStreamError StrError = SendAll();
            if( StrError != CameraStreamError::Success )
            {
                return StrError;
            }
        }
        else if( Result == AVERROR_EOF )
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            STREAM_ERROR( WriteFailed );
        }
    }

    int Result = av_write_trailer( ID.FormatContext );
    if( Result < 0 )
    {
        STREAM_ERROR( WriteFailed );
    }

    if( !(ID.FormatContext->oformat->flags& AVFMT_NOFILE) )
    {
        Result = avio_close( ID.FormatContext->pb );
        if( Result < 0 )
        {
            STREAM_ERROR( WriteFailed );
        }
    }

    return CameraStreamError::Success;
}
```

Note I've simplified a few things and inlined a few bits that were elsewhere. I've also removed all the shutdown code as anything that happens after the file is closed is irrelevant.

Full repo here: https://github.com/IanNorris/Witness If you clone this the issue is with the 'Diagnostics' output, the Output file is fine. There are two hardcoded paths to X:.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `avio_write()` file is not a MP4 file, it's simply the compressed H.264 packets in sequence, also known as AnnexB H.264.

To write files in a container using `av_interleaved_frame_write()`, you also need to call [`avformat_write_header()`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga18b7b10bb5b94c4842de18166bc677cb) before and [`av_write_trailer()`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#ga7f14007e7dc8f481f054b21614dfec13) after all the compressed video/audio packets. Without that, the file won't contain global headers (such as the `moov` chunk in MP4) and won't be recognized as a valid file by external applications, as the error here indeed indicates.

Also see the more detailed description in the [muxing documentation](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavf__encoding.html#details).

Comment: Thanks! I actually had these in the code, but your answer made me check it was being called. It was - but not for BOTH files, only the first. This was caused by a missing destructor. It now works as expected.